# python: printing a list, & special-casing dicts

Tags: python, polymorphism

I have a list which has items that are either `dict`s or something else.

I want to write a method which prints the list, each item on a line, but special-cases the dicts; something like:

```
def printSpecialList(mylist):
  for item in mylist:
    if itemIsDict(item):
      printDictItem(item)
    else:
      print str(item)
```

I can implement everything but `itemIsDict` -- what's the simplest way to do that?

---

just a clarification:

The source of this list produces items using dictionary literals e.g. `{'a': 3, 'b': 4}`, which makes it cumbersome to use special dictionary types that know how to format themselves. In addition, my `printSpecialList` method is a little more complicated, and it has its own private state that it incorporates, so instance testing, albeit "yucky" (e.g. someone couldn't make a mock dict class that doesn't descend from dict that would work with my method) seems like the best way to go here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
def itemIsDict(item):
    return isinstance(item, dict)
```

Answer (score 2):

`isinstance(item, dict)` would do what you're asking, but it has to be said that branching on the type of a variable is rather un-Pythonic.

Comment: I'm aware of that, but I don't see any real alternative: a `dict` object doesn't know how to format itself the way I want, whereas I do.

Answer (score 2):

You can subclass `dict` and implement the `__repr__` or `__str__` method:

```
class MyDict(dict):

    __str__(self):
        # you write your custom string format
        return 'my custom formatted string'
```

This way your code will handle every item in the same way:

```
for item in mylist:
    print item
```

**Note:** If you want to follow this approach more information can be found in the [official documentation](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__)

Comment: I understand that, but I have existing code that makes this list, and I don't want it to have to use MyDict instead of literals like `{'a': 3, 'b': 4}`

Answer (score 0):

By using `type()`

```
if type(item) == dict:
    print "Dictionary!"
```

Comment: Except that this doesn't recognize subtypes of `dict`, even such objects are, for (almost) all intents and purposes, perfectly valid dictionaries.

Comment: Ah, so that's the difference between type and isinstance?  Thanks, I didn't know that.